# Azure Table Storage Delete where Row Key is Between two Row Key Values

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Is there a good way to delete entities that are in the same partition given a row key range? It looks like the only way to do this would be to do a range lookup and then batch the deletes after looking them up. I'll know my range at the time that entities will be deleted so I'd rather skip the lookup.

I want to be able to delete things to keep my partitions from getting too big. As far as I know a single partition cannot be scaled across multiple servers. Each partition is going to represent a type of message that a user sends. There will probably be less than 50 types. I need a way to show all the messages of each type that were sent (ex: show recent messages regardless of who sent it of type 0). This is why I plan to make the type the partition key. Since the types don't scale with the number of users/messages though I don't want to let each partition grow indefinitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to know precise Partition Keys and Row Keys in order to issue deletes.  You do not need to retrieve entities from storage if you know precise RowKeys, but you do need to have them in order to issue batch delete.  There is no magic "Delete from table where partitionkey = 10" command like there is in SQL.

However, consider breaking your data up into tables that represent archivable time units.  For example in [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) we store all of the metric data into tables that represent one month of data.  IE: Metrics201401, Metrics201402, etc.  Thus, when it comes time to archive, a full table is purged for a particular month.

The obvious downside of this approach is the need to "union" data from multiple tables if your queries span wide time ranges.  However, if your keep your time ranges to minimum quantity, amount of unions will not be as big.  Basically, this approach allows you to utilize table name as another partitioning opportunity.

Comment: That works for me. None of the lookups to be done on these tables should span more than a partition so I don't think making each partition it's own table would cause any problems. Thanks!